# scikit-learn/k-meansを使った画像のクラスタリングでのエラー

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

ディレクトリ内のjpg画像ファイルをSURFを用いて、特徴量を抽出し、すべてのSURFをk-means法でグループ化して基本特徴量(visual word)を求め、これを使って画像の局所特徴量リストをbag-of-wordsリストにするプログラムがあります。
試しに、90枚ほどの画像でやるとうまくグループわけができましたが、いざ1900枚ほどの画像でやってみると、以下のエラーメッセージが出てきました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 27, in <module>
    c = km.predict(d)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 1460, in predict
X = self._check_test_data(X)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 794, in _check_test_data warn_on_dtype=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_array context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 64)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

どうすれば正しく実行できますでしょうか？
以下、コードです。

```
import mahotas as mh
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from mahotas.features import surf
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

picture_category_num = 5
feature_category_num = 128

# image surf
images = glob('./*.jpg')
alldescriptors = []
for im in images:
  im = mh.imread(im, as_grey=True)
  im = im.astype(np.uint8)
  alldescriptors.append(surf.surf(im, descriptor_only=True))

# image surf -> basic feature
concatenated = np.concatenate(alldescriptors)
km = MiniBatchKMeans(feature_category_num)
km.fit(concatenated)

# image surf and basic feature -> features
features = []
for d in alldescriptors:
  c = km.predict(d)
  features.append(np.array([np.sum(c == ci) for ci in range(feature_category_num)]))
features = np.array(features)

# features -> tfidf
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(features)
tfidf.toarray() 
# not use tfidf
# tfidf = features

# categorization
km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=picture_category_num, init='random', n_init=1, verbose=1)
km.fit(tfidf)

# print result
images = np.array(images)
print('completed')
f = open("result.txt","w")
for i in range(picture_category_num):
  print('image category{0}'.format(i), file=f)
  print(images[km.labels_ == i], file=f)
else:
  f.close()
```

Comment: エラーメッセージを見ますと、その1900枚の画像の中に SURF で特徴量を抽出できない画像が含まれているのではないかと思います。例えば、`if d.size > 0: c = km.predict(d)` とするか、特徴量 0 の画像は `alldescriptors` に `append` しない様にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: if d.size > 0: c = km.predict(d)としたところ、しっかりと結果を出力することができました！ありがとうございました！確かに特徴量が抽出で来てない画像を配列に入れてもできないですね・・・。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージを見ますと、その1900枚の画像の中に SURF で特徴量を抽出できない画像が含まれているのではないかと思います。例えば、

```
if d.size > 0:
    c = km.predict(d)
```

とするか、特徴量 0 の画像は `alldescriptors` に `append` しない様にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

<sub>-- この投稿は、[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27009/scikit-learn-k-means%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC#comment25761_27009)をコミュニティ wiki として投稿したものです。</sub>