# k-means法sickit-learn　クラスタリング　エラー解決方法

Tags: python, scikit-learn

心拍センサで取得したデータをcsvファイルへ保存しread_csvを行いk-means法を用いて２種類（感情別（画像参照；１、落ち着いている　２、イライラしている））にクラスタリングしたいのですが、

```
ValueError; Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(30,0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

というエラーが発生し、エラーの解決策がわからず困っております。
取得したデータのcsvファイルへの書き込み方が悪いのでしょうか？

ソースコードです

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
colors = ['red','blue']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd

def main():
    # クラスタ数
    N_CLUSTERS = 2

    # Blob データを生成する
    ##dataset = datasets.make_blobs(centers=N_CLUSTERS)

    # 正解ラベルは使わない
    # targets = dataset[1]
    data = pd.read_csv('heartRate1.csv',names=('cute','ang'))

    del(data['cute'])
    del(data['ang'])

    data_array = data.as_matrix().T

    # 特徴データ
    features = data_array.T

    # クラスタリングする
    cls = KMeans(n_clusters=N_CLUSTERS)
    pred = cls.fit_predict(features)

    # 各要素をラベルごとに色付けして表示する


    ##for i in range(N_CLUSTERS):
       ## labels = features[pred == i]
    plt.scatter(labels[:, 0], labels[:, 1], c=pred, cmap=cmap)

    # クラスタのセントロイド (重心) を描く
    centers = cls.cluster_centers_
    plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], s=80,
                marker='p', edgecolors='k', c=range(N_CLUSTERS), cmap=cmap)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

csvファイルの中身です

[image: csvファイルの中身です]

Comment: 重複候補： [scikit-learn/k-meansを使った画像のクラスタリングでのエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/27009/3060)

Comment: @loudog さん、もし解決したということでしたら回答横のチェックマークから回答を承認いただけると助かります。あわせて[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)もご覧くださいませ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = pd.read_csv('heartRate1.csv', names=('cute','ang'))
del(data['cute'])
del(data['ang'])
```

この部分で CSV から読み取ったデータを全て消してしまっています。このため、この後 KMeans をしようとしたところでデータが無いのにクラスタリングしようとして今回のエラー `Found array with 0 feature(s)` が出ています。

おそらく [`del` 文](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)の挙動を勘違いなさっているのではないかと思うので、なぜ `del` しているのかを確認してみてください。

#### 補足

一応こちらの手元では、以下のようにしたら良さ気に動きました。

- `del` はどちらもコメントアウト
- `matplotlib.pyplot` も `import`
- `plt.scatter` に渡す `x`, `y` は `labels` ではなく `features`

また以下の警告が出ていたので、将来的には対応しておく方が良いでしょう。

```
FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
  data_array = data.as_matrix().T
```